# Custom prediction method for inference phase of a LSTM stacked layers model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, predict

I do some multivariate time series forecasting to design a one-step ahead predictor using Keras API and a stacked Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) layers, so I'm tune and fit the following sequential model:

```
n_steps_in = 1
n_features = 3
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(15, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps_in,n_features)))
model.add(LSTM(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_features))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train_lstm, y_train_lstm, epochs=100, validation_data = (X_test_lstm, y_test_lstm), 
            verbose=1)
```

After that, In inference phase, I would like to use a my custom predict method instead of using the buit-in predict Keras method. To do so, fistly I have extract the weights and bias form the fitted model, and create a method that predict only one single time step i.e. I give to the fitted model an input sample with shape `(1,1,3)` and then it outputs a predicted vector with shape `(1,3)`. This method is little similar than doing a feedforward pass.

```
def model_predict_LSTM(model, input_pred, c_tm1, h_tm1):



    # for layer in model.layers:
    #     if "LSTM" in str(layer):
    #         weightLSTM = layer.get_weights()
    # warr,uarr, barr = weightLSTM
    # warr.shape,uarr.shape,barr.shape

    #Layer_0
    units0 = int(int(model.layers[0].trainable_weights[0].shape[1])/4)
    print("Num units0: ", units0)

    W0 = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
    U0 = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]
    b0 = model.layers[0].get_weights()[2]

    # Every LSTM cell contain 4 trainable weights (input gate, forget gate, new_candidate, output         gate)
    # Keras API divide them to W, U and b. W is the trainable weights for the input sequences
    # U is the trainable weights for the hidden states and b is the bias vector. 

    W0_i = W0[:, :units0]
    W0_f = W0[:, units0: units0 * 2]
    W0_c = W0[:, units0 * 2: units0 * 3]
    W0_o = W0[:, units0 * 3:]

    U0_i = U0[:, :units0]
    U0_f = U0[:, units0: units0 * 2]
    U0_c = U0[:, units0 * 2: units0 * 3]
    U0_o = U0[:, units0 * 3:]

    b0_i = b0[:units0]
    b0_f = b0[units0: units0 * 2]
    b0_c = b0[units0 * 2: units0 * 3]
    b0_o = b0[units0 * 3:]

    i0_t = sigmoid(np.dot(input_pred, W0_i)+np.dot(h_tm1, U0_i)+b0_i)    
    f0_t = sigmoid(np.dot(input_pred, W0_f)+np.dot(h_tm1, U0_f)+b0_f)
    o0_t = sigmoid(np.dot(input_pred, W0_o)+np.dot(h_tm1, U0_o)+b0_o)
    new_candidate0_t = tanh(np.dot(input_pred, W0_c)+np.dot(h_tm1, U0_c)+b0_c)
    c0_t = np.dot(f0_t, c_tm1)+np.dot(i0_t, new_candidate0_t)
    h0_t = np.dot(o0_t, tanh(c0_t))

    #Layer_1
    units1 = int(int(model.layers[1].trainable_weights[0].shape[1])/4)
    print("Num units1: ", units1)

    W1 = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
    U1 = model.layers[1].get_weights()[1]
    b1 = model.layers[1].get_weights()[2]

    W1_i = W1[:, :units1]
    W1_f = W1[:, units1: units1 * 2]
    W1_c = W1[:, units1 * 2: units1 * 3]
    W1_o = W1[:, units1 * 3:]

    U1_i = U1[:, :units1]
    U1_f = U1[:, units1: units1 * 2]
    U1_c = U1[:, units1 * 2: units1 * 3]
    U1_o = U1[:, units1 * 3:]

    b1_i = b1[:units1]
    b1_f = b1[units1: units1 * 2]
    b1_c = b1[units1 * 2: units1 * 3]
    b1_o = b1[units1 * 3:]

    i1_t = sigmoid(np.dot(input_pred, W1_i)+np.dot(h0_t, U1_i)+b1_i)    
    f1_t = sigmoid(np.dot(input_pred, W1_f)+np.dot(h0_t, U1_f)+b1_f)
    o1_t = sigmoid(np.dot(input_pred, W1_o)+np.dot(h0_t, U1_o)+b1_o)
    new_candidate1_t = tanh(np.dot(input_pred, W1_c)+np.dot(h0_t, U1_c)+b1_c)
    c1_t = np.dot(f1_t, c0_t)+np.dot(i1_t, new_candidate1_t)
    h1_t = np.dot(o1_t, tanh(c1_t))


    #Layer_2
    dense_weights = model.layers[2].get_weights()[0]
    dense_bias = model.layers[2].get_weights()[1]
    dense_output=np.dot(h1_t, dense_weights)+dense_bias
    output_pred = layer3_output.reshape(1, 3)

    return output_pred
```

My problem is I cannot get the prediction because I don't really understand how does the input vector propagates in the LSTM layers, the reccurent propagation (between LSTM cells) and the forward propagation (between LSTM layers) despite I read many blogs and papers talking about this topic. They usually use the built-in methods. Finally I would be grateful if someone helps me to create my custom predict method instead of using the Keras API built-in method to perform prediction. Thanks in advance

Comment: You might find tensorflow custom training loop useful for your solution.

Comment: That's a lot of code. I don't understand: What's wrong with just doing the forward pass?

" I cannot get the prediction" - What goes wrong?